# Node JS allowing constants to be changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Why does node.js allow a module (or an object) specified as a constant to be changed?

For example, this is allowed:

```
const EXPRESS = require('express');
EXPRESS.someProperty = 'some value';
```

But this is not:

```
const MYCONST = '123';
MYCONST = '456';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`const` means that you cannot change the reference itself, not what the reference points to.

```
const a = { name: 'tom' };

// you cannot change the reference (point a to something else)
a = 5; // this is an error

// but you can change the value stored at that reference with no problem
a.name = 'bob';
```

Comment: All good answers. Thanks for the explanation guys.

Answer (score 4):

const does not make the object to become immutable thus you can change the object itself but you can not assign another object to that reference

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in case the content is
>   an object, this means the object itself can still be altered.

This isn't node-specific, it is part of the Javascript spec. The reference `EXPRESS` is the constant, and when you declare using `const` you are not allowed to reassign the reference.

```
const EXPRESS = require('express');
EXPRESS = 'something else';
```

would also fail